# scroll to top with turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

scroll to top is not working with turbolinks

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 800) {
            $('#scroll-to-top').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('#scroll-to-top').fadeOut();
        }
    });
    $('#scroll-to-top').click(function () {
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 400);
        return false;
    });
});
```

I tried to use data-no-turbolink in a button, but it doesn't help me.

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks to fix the `$(document).ready(function()` issues with turbolinks?

Comment: @Anton did you ever find a resolution for this?